# python 2.7 mass zip file extraction to target directory

Tags: python, zip, os.walk

I'm trying to iterate through a folder of zipped files and extract them to a target directory. My code is:

```
import os
import zipfile

def mass_extract():
    source_directory = raw_input("Where are the zips? ")

    if not os.path.exists(source_directory):
        print "Sorry, that folder doesn't seem to exist."
        source_directory = raw_input("Where are the zips? ")

    target_directory = raw_input("To where do you want to extract the files? ")
    if not os.path.exists(target_directory):
        os.mkdir(target_directory)

    for path, directory, filename in os.walk(source_directory):
        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'w')
        zipfile.extract(zip_file, target_directory)
        zip_file.close()

    print "Done."
```

I'm getting two errors here:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'extract'
Exception AttributeError:"'list' object has no attribute 'tell'" in <bound method ZipFile.__del__ of <zipfile.ZipFile object at 0xb701d52c>> ignored
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Both errors are likely caused by the fact that [`extract`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract) is a member of the `zip_file` object, not the `zipfile` module.

Comment: it's good form to use the context manager: `with zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'w') as zip_file:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `zipfile.extract` to `zip_file.extractall`

Edit: Back from mobile, here is some cleaner code. I noticed the inital code would not run as is because 'filename' is actually a list of files for that directory. Also, opening it as `write` aka `w` will just overwrite your existing zip files, you don't want that.

```
for path, directory, filenames in os.walk(source_directory):
    for each_file in filenames:
        file_path = os.path.join(path, each_file)
        if os.path.splitext(file_path)[1] == ".zip": # Make sure it's a zip file
            with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path) as zip_file:
                zip_file.extractall(path=target_directory)
```

[Here](https://github.com/cdgriffith/Reusables/blob/master/reusables/reusables.py#L506) is an example of zipfile code in use I did a while ago.